# ADF Glassfish Autodeploy Error

Tags: glassfish-3, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, autodeploy

I am able to deploy an adf application to glassfish server from jDeveloper directly (and the application runs fine too), but when I deploy an EAR file and then put it into the autodeploy folder of my glassfish domain I see the following error in my log (FYI: I had undeployed and restarted glassfish before loading the ear file to autodeploy directory)

```
[#|2013-03-21T06:27:17.104-0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.share.glassfish.listener.ADFGlassFishAppLifeCycleListener
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5332)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to error message you don't have ADF libraries installed either on your glassfish domain completly or at this server instance.

Check [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/admin.111230/e16179/ap_glassfish.htm#ADFAG20931) if you need to install full version of ADF to the weblogic server.
Or if you planning to use free version of ADF - ADF Essentials, try to follow this [post](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/deploying_oracle_adf_applications_to).